# Extending interface to change contract, but not API

Tags: java, interface

(I am unsure if title terminology is correct.)

Suppose I am trying to create some abstraction for readable, writable, and read- and writable "properties". Depending on the situation, I might want to accept only readable properties, only writable properties, or both (read- and writable). However, suppose I want both types of properties to derive their core methods from the same supertype, but I also want to maintain type safety (e.g. if I request a readable property I want to be assured I will get a readable property).

Here is what a `Property` super-interface might look like:

```
public interface Property {
    // Readable property core methods

    /**
     * Blah blah...
     * @throws UnsupportedOperationException if this property is not readable.
     */
    X readAsX();
    ...

    // Writable property core methods

    /**
     * Blah blah...
     * @throws UnsupportedOperationException if this property is not writable.
     */
    void writeX(X value);
    ...
}
```

The important thing to note is that it is specified to throw `UnsupportedOperationException` as appropriate if a `Property` is not readable/writable.

Now, would the following be an appropriate way to define a `ReadableProperty`? (`WritableProperty` would be defined similarly.)

```
public interface ReadableProperty extends Property {
    // Readable property core methods

    /**
     * Blah blah...
     * Not allowed to throw UnsupportedOperationException: must be readable!
     */
    X readAsX();
    ...

    // Writable property core methods

    /**
     * Always throws UnsupportedOperationException: this property is not writable.
     */
    default void writeX(X value) {
        throw new UnsupportedOperationException();
    }
    ...
}
```

Note no new methods have been added; all that has changed is the existing methods have a stricter specification. Is this an appropriate design for the situation described?

(Note: this scenario is fictional. I am more concerned with the idea than this specific application of it.)

Comment: The one obvious reason this is insufficient is that `default` methods can be overridden. As for the rest, I'd let this decision of *readable* or *writable* be determined at *concrete* implementation levels. It really doesn't make much sense to have an *interface* that only adds the specificity about these readable/writable attributes.

Comment: Your approach is legitimate. The same is used in Lists' implementations, where some operations are optional. But this lead to headaches. How do you know if an implementation implements one of the optional operation or not? This seems like an anti-pattern to me. Better to have WritableProperty/ReadableProperty interfaces, and an ``interface Property extends WritableProperty, ReadableProperty``.

Comment: @ernest_k Yeah, that is the concerning part: there is nothing technically stopping a `ReadableProperty` from being writable or vice versa. Then again, when an interface specifies that a method should return some specific integer attribute of the described type, for example, there's nothing stopping the implementer from returning a random integer. Nonetheless, there's certainly better ways to do this. Interesting to see this approach is used in java collections, though.

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you simply use two abstract classes implementing only one method each?

```
public abstract class ReadableProperty implements Property {
// Readable property core methods
// Writable property core methods

/**
 * Always throws UnsupportedOperationException: this property is not writable.
 */
@Override
final void writeX(X value) {
    throw new UnsupportedOperationException();
}
```

}

Actually you're implementing a method of an interface, not defining a default behaviour for a newly introduced signature in an interface (that's the main reason for which the default modifier as been introduced)

Answer (score 1):

I would have an abstract class Property holding common operations between read and write, a ReadProperty that extends this abstract class and implement a Read operation and a WriteProperty that extends this abstract class and implement a Read operation.

By having an Unsupported operation in your interface, you're violating the Liskov Substitution principle. Retake a look at SOLID principles.

You can pass this Abstract class as parameter to your function, and when processing check whether it implements read or write interface.